# Error on force:navigateToSObject in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

I get an 'Uncaught error in $A.run() : Cannot read property 'runDeprecated' of undefined' whenever i put the force:navigateToSObject inside the aura:iteration

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="c">
<div onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}">Click Me!</div>
</aura:iteration>
```

it works if i place it outside the aura:iteration but i need it inside to navigate through the items of the iteration.

Comment: Why did you name your var "c"? You might be running into some naming conflicts, try changing the var name to "account".

Comment: Tried it and it solved my problem. Thanks alot!! @MosheKarmel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Moshe mentioned, setting your account to var="c" is the issue. Now it's trying to find navigateToRecord on the account which doesn't exist.

setting var="account" would fix it.